# How to crawl text embedded in tooltips using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, hover, web-crawler, tooltip

I'd like to crawl the data that is embedded in a tooltip which becomes visible when you hover over the cell where the tooltip belongs to.

For example, I'd like to extract the tooltip in the row *10Bet* and column *1* using scrapy (via splash requests) of

https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/morocco/wta-rabat-2017/saville-daria-zanevska-maryna-r9VW6N40/

Answer (score -1):

These tooltips are just `title` attributes

You tagged you question as `javascript` so:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('p').title)
```

```html
<p title="hidden text">Some text with tooltip</p>
```

Comment: can you provide the xpath to extract the opening odds?

Comment: *response.css("span#tooltiptext.spc.spc-nowrap").extract()* yields empty list